# How to make a Login Form appear once every 24 hours in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, forms, server

The title isn't explaining much, sorry. I will try to explain what I need here.

So I have a login form in my C# Program (Winforms) that sends you to the Main Form after successfully logging in.

What i want to do here is make that form only appear once after logging in, for example. every time you open the program you won't have to login again, just once.

However after 24 hours pass (preferably in a some-what server way so when the pc is off the timer still counts) the login form appears again for login (the user will have to get a new key)

Sorry if i asked too much, thanks in advance!

Comment: store the login information in some place(disk for example), use these login information before user login window appears.

Comment: @dexiang that would be permanent, i want it to do that every 24 hours since a different key will be used

Comment: Log them out on the server after 24 hours. I'm not saying you have to actively log them out at the 24-hour mark (which seems to be the flaw in your thinking), but any requests 24 hours or more after login should trigger a logout.

Comment: I don't even have a server and i have no idea how to make it that's why I'm asking here.